# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) C++ - Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm pretty new to pointers and I'm assigned to do this array doubling task but whenever I run my code I get a Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped) error.
Can someone look at my code and tell me where the error is coming from and what I can do to fix it?

I'm very stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
                   int size = length;
                   string *new_array = NULL;
                   string *tmp_array = new string[50];
                   for(int k=0; k<50; k++)//Initial array copying.
                       tmp_array[k] = wordArray[k];

                   for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)//Array range 0 to n-1
                   {
                      new_array = new string[size*2];
                      for(int j=0; j<size; j++)//Array range 0 to n-1
                      {
                         new_array[j]=tmp_array[j];
                         new_array[j+size]="empty";
                      }
                      delete[] tmp_array; //Deleting old array
                      size=size*2; 
                  }
                  delete[] tmp_array;// To free memory
                  cout<<new_array[x]<<endl;
```

There error is somewhere in there. 
There is no other pointer reference in any of the code.

Thanks

Comment: What if `wordArray` has less than 50 elements?  Your first `for` loop would have a buffer overrun.  Also, this is overly complicated for simply allocating more space for an array.  Two calls to `new[]` to do this?  And why not simply use `std::vector`?  In any event, Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Prefer using smart pointers instead of regular pointers.  Prefer `std::vector` to dynamic arrays.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)//Array range 0 to n-1` the comment LIES! *LIIIIEEESSS!* You get two iterations: i=0 and i=1. After than i>1 and exits. Other than that, Fire up your IDE's debugger and start stepping through your code. Couple good reasons to do this: 1. Knowing how to use debuggers will save you vast amounts of time in the long run. 2. Five bucks says the debugger will show you exactly where the problem is and, if you take a look at the state of your variables when it happens,  exactly how it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access `tmp_array` after it's been `delete`d.

```
for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)//Array range 0 to n-1
{
   new_array = new string[size*2];
   for(int j=0; j<size; j++)//Array range 0 to n-1
   {
      new_array[j]=tmp_array[j];
      new_array[j+size]="empty";
   }

   // The deleted tmp_array is used in the next iteration of the loop,
   delete[] tmp_array; //Deleting old array

   //===============================
   // Add this to fix the problem
   //===============================
   tmp_array = new_array;

   size=size*2; 
}
```